# Sending class object to template class not working

Tags: c++, oop

I am trying to sending an object to another template class in C++ but i am getting an error. Here is code. How can i solve this problem? I want to create an Queue with Passenger type.

MAIN.CPP

```
#include<iostream>
#include "Queue.h"

class Passenger{
    private:
        string name,surname,destination;
    public:
        Passenger (string name, string surname, string destination)
        {
            this->name = name;
            this->surname = surname;
            this->destination = destination;
        }
int main()
{
    Queue<Passenger> passenger;
    passenger.insertQueue(Passenger("Batuhan","Gunes","Istanbul")); //HERE IS ERROR
    return 0;
}
```

Queue.h

```
#ifndef Queue_h
#define Queue_h
#include<iostream>
#include<cassert>
using namespace std;


template <class T>
class Queue{
        int max;
        int count;
        int front, rear;
        T *list;
    public:
        Queue(int = 100)

        //Inserts a new item to the queue. Inserts are always dont at the rear
        void insertQueue(T& item);
};


template <class T>
void Queue<T>::insertQueue(T& item)
{
    if(!isFull())
    {
        rear = (rear+1) % max;
        list[rear] = item;
        count++;
    }
    else
    {
        cerr<<"No space left in the queue!"<<endl;
    }
}
```

ERROR MESSAGE
[Error] no matching function for call to 'Queue::insertQueue(Passenger)'

Comment: Still I can't solve issue! DONT CLOSE MY POST HELP ME!

Comment: Did you read the linked question? Which part of the explanation of the reason for your compilation error, in the linked question, you still have a question about? Do you understand its explanation for this compilation error? Did you read the answer to the linked question?